# Problem with Literature

Tags: bibliographies

I am currently writing on my thesis and therefore created a bibliography. At some point in the bibliography, the literature breaks out of the block until the end of the bibliography. Until then everything is looking fine. I do not know how to explain this properly so I created some screenshots.
[image]

Here you can see what I mean. At the line at the end of the page you can see how the block should be intended. But at this one point latex suddenly widens the block and I do not understand why. I use overleaf if this is important for you.

[image]

At this snippet, you can see how the source looks like.

Has someone experienced this problem already or have any clue what is going on here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please add the code directly to the question, in the form of a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/172164) - a piece of your code starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending in `\end{document}` that someone else can run to reproduce the problem. This allows people to test it directly, which is much easier to throubleshoot. You can also directly include the relevant content of the .bib file in your question [like this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/172164).

Comment: I'd bet that this is caused by a special character (quite probably an underscore `_`) in the DOI of *Kozhevnikov et al.*. One would expect that the `.bst` file can handle those characters gracefully, but apparently that is not the case. Unfortunately, we can only suggest a good solution if we know more about the bibliography style you use, the bibliography and citation packages you load and if we can confirm that the `.bib` entry really contains an `_`. So please try to post a small example document with only a few citations and nothing more that reproduces the issue (see comment above).

Comment: Hello, sry for the late response. You were right! There was an underscore in the DOI of Kozhevnikov. Removing it solves the problem. Thank you so much!